# How do i use actions to change the view of my pie chart in Tableau?

Tags: business-intelligence, tableau-desktop

So i am learning about Tableau and wanted to figure something out, I have created a Pie Chart visual which displays my Brand Share by region as a Percentage below:
[image]

**I want to change my view where once i click my map on Dashboard this visual goes from the current above to Top 3 Brands by SUM(2021) per country.**

Currently when i click my map on my Dashboard, this visual changes to 100% of the country selected but i suppose that is expected based on my filters etc.

Answer (score 0):

We need  to create a Set and a Parameter. Here's the link:
https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/sortgroup_sets_topn.htm

Here's how it works on the Sample superstore data.
[image]

[image]

Comment: I did notice this during research on it, does this allow for displaying the alternate view using actions? This example seems to expand and collapse data instead of adjusting the view.

Comment: Also this visual will be used as a separate visual not on the map itself. But the visual should change once the map is clicked, to represent top 3 brands for selected country.